# Combine solr's document score with a static, indexed score in solr 7.x

Tags: solr, lucene, information-retrieval

I have people indexed into solr based on structured documents. For simplicity's sake, let's say they have the following schema

```
{      
  personName: text,
  games :[ { gamerScore: int, game: text } ]
}
```

An example of the above would be

```
{     
 personName: john,
 games: [
   { gamerScore: 80, game: Zelda },
   { gamerScore: 20, game: Space Invader },
   { gamerScore: 60, game: Tetris},
 ]
}
```

'gamerScore' (a value between 1 and 100 to indicate how good the person is in the specified game). 
**Relevance matching** in solr is all done through the Text field 'game'. However, I want my final result list to be a combination of relevance to the query as provided by solr and my own gamerScore. Namely, I need to re-rank the results based on the following formula:

```
personFinalScore = (0.8 * solrScore) + (0.2 * gamerScore)
```

What am trying to achieve is the combination of two different scores in a weighted manner in solr. This question was asked [a long time ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18449810/combine-solrs-document-score-with-a-static-indexed-score), and was wondering if there is something in solr v7.x. that can tackle this.

I can change the schema around if a solution requires it.

Answer (score 0):

In effect your formula can be simplified to applying your gamerScore with 0.25 - the absolute value of the score is irrelevant, just how much the gamerScore field affects the score of the document.

The `dismax` based handlers supports `bf`:

> The bf parameter specifies functions (with optional boosts) that will
>   be used to construct FunctionQueries which will be added to the user’s
>   main query as optional clauses that will influence the score.

Since `bf` is an addtive boost, you can use `bf=product(gamerScore,0.25)` to make the `gamerScore` count 20% of the total score.

Comment: thank you, I might be missing something. Here is an example, how would your suggestion work if hypothetically, we have 3 players and all three played multiple games and they also played "Zelda" and they have the following scores for "Zelda" [Player1: 30, Player2: 50, Player3: 5].  if I search for Zelda, The results should come up as P2, P1, P3.  I don't see how the function boost can work here. Or how it can take the Zelda Score only and compare it to other player's Zelda scores.

Comment: In your example you don't need any boosting - a simple `sort=zelda desc` would suffice. You'd index the "zelda" score into a field named `zelda` in that case, and order by it. Boosting is useful for what you described - moving other results around based on a different factor, not straight up ordering. To apply it as a boost to achieve your formula, index it into a field named as the game as well, then apply that as a boost as described.

Comment: Are you saying I should create a dynamic filed called "game_*" and at insertion time it would be "game_zelda" with a static value as above. if so, what would happen at query time? for instance, if a person query for a game that I don't have any player for. Example game_SLKHF. Moreover, what happens when the query contain multiple games. I understand sort will not take into account all the games then sort, rather sort on the first field, and then the second and so forth.
"

Comment: Correct. At query time the boost from the field will be applied if the field exists. Boosting changes the score of documents - possibly reordering them - the selection of documents isn't affected. You'll use `fq` for that (or the regular query). If the query contains multiple games that you've detected, you add them as separate fields and add boosts for each game.

Comment: To add to my previous comment - the best way to actually implement this (through game detection) is to first use the query to search a collection with valid games, then use the list returned from that collection to generate field names (i.e. `game_<game_id>`, where `game_id` is unique for that game (i.e. `zelda` or `zelda_2`, etc.).